# Can't call web api controller inside the signalr OnDisconnected method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an mvc web apllication with signalr and i want to update the table in the published web api.

calling web api controller to get users inside the `Onconnected` method works fine:

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
{ 
    var users = await _client.GetAsync("chats/users");
    Clients.All.userConnected();
}
```

But when i place the code inside the `OnDisconnected` method it gives me an error:

```
public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
     var users = await _client.GetAsync("chats/users");
}
```

Why is this happening? this is the whole `Hub` code:

```
private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
private HttpClient _client;

public ChatHub()
{
    AccessDelegatingHandler handler = new AccessDelegatingHandler();

    _client = HttpClientFactory.Create(handler);
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ClsConfig.GetConfiguration().APIBaseAddress);
}

// Send new message to group chat.
public static void SendGroupMessage(MessageDetailModel messageDetail)
{
    hubContext.Clients.All.newGroupMessageReceived(messageDetail);
}

public override async Task OnConnected()
{ 
    var users = await _client.GetAsync("chats/users");

    Clients.All.userConnected();
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    return base.OnReconnected();
}

public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    var users = await _client.GetAsync("chats/users");
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found out that when i place `var user = Context.User.Identity;` inside the `OnDisconnected` method the user is `IsAuthenticated = true` but when i place a break point inside the `AccessDelegatingHandler` class the `var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;` line gives an error and is `IsAuthenticated = false`

Answer (score 0):

By the time the onDisconnected event fires, you are likely already disconnected, and there is no guarantee that your code will run, (its a known issue with Signalr) also are you monitoring the onDisconnected in the client or the server? It looks like you are trying to handle it from the server, and you should be handling it from the client.

This link should help to understand why this is the way it is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#clientdisconnect

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yes i am handling it on server because the problem is when i handle it on client side when the browser or window was closed, the function that will update the database will not be fired. what i'm trying to do is to update user IsOnline = false